# ffprobe count video and audio streams / tracks

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

So I have the following video example

```
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 (High 10), yuv420p10le(progressive), 1920x1036 [SAR 1:1 DAR 480:259], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 640 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:2(jpn): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 640 kb/s
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English Signs & Songs
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      title           : English Subtitles
    Stream #0:5: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : PutoInsanity.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
```

I want to use *ffprobe* to count the amount of video streams and audio streams, which in this case should give me **1** and **2** resp. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such feature, but you can use `ffprobe` plus additional tools such as `uniq` (and `sort` if desired) to process the output.

## List number of stream types

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_type -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mkv | uniq -c
      1 data
      1 video
      1 attachment
      8 subtitle
      6 audio
```

## Just output number for specific stream type

Or a piecemeal method. This example shows how many audio streams there are:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=index -of csv=p=0 input.mkv | wc -w
2
```

Accepted values for `-select_streams`:

- `v` video
- `V` video (excluding attached pictures, video thumbnails or cover art).
- `a` audio
- `s` subtitles
- `d` data
- `t` attachments

Comment: FYI, this also works for subtitles, such as:
`ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_type input.mkv | grep "codec_type=subtitle" | wc -w)`

Comment: @MrPotatoHead Reminded me of `uniq`. Answer updated.

Comment: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html and here, but probably can only specify 1 stream type at a time =/